# Where does the namespace stores in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I want to find the location of the saved namespace ie., saved metadata in the hadoop when i give the command hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace in the cloudera Distribution.

Can some one help me where can i find the saved namespace file path in the cloudera.

Comment: I think it shows the save location when your run the command. The data will be stored on your local disk.

Answer (score 1):

In a **highly-available NameNod**e configuration, the command `hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace` sets a checkpoint in the first NameNode specified in the configuration, in `dfs.ha.namenodes.[nameserviceID]`.

You can also use the `dfsadmin -fsoption` to specify which NameNode to connect. For example, to **force a checkpoint in NameNode2**: `hdfs dfsadmin -fs hdfs://namenode2-hostname:namenode2-port -saveNamespace`

Checkpoint files are located in `${dfs.namenode.name.dir}/current`

Comment: Am a fresher and amble to understand a few could you please elaborate in detail which will help me a lot, or can some one help me in this in detail

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.nameservices
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**